# Bigquery Subfunction Cannot create additional columns

Tags: google-bigquery

I had a script in BigQuery like:

```
Select 
a_random_name as a_understandable_name
b_random_name as b_understandable_name
start_time

concat(a_random_name,b_random_name) as extended_name,
DATETIME_TRUNC(start_time,DAY) as Day

FROM 'my_table'
```

But I wanted to use the understandable names in my script for further work so I try to use a nested query :

```
select * from
(Select 
a_random_name as a_understandable_name
b_random_name as b_understandable_name
start_time

FROM 'my_table')
```

```
concat(a_understandable_name,b_understandable_name) as extended_name,
DATETIME_TRUNC(start_time,DAY) as Day
```

I'm trying to move transformations e.g the concat, DateTime_Trunc after the import and rename query but I get errors on the 'AS' statements in concat and DateTime_Trunc - it seems like the issue is I cannot create columns here?

If I use

```
concat(a_understandable_name,b_understandable_name)
DATETIME_TRUNC(start_time,DAY)
```

it works but I cannot see any columns in the output  where these calculations were performed
FWIW I'm a beginner so this is probably something basic.

Comment: Please format your code, read [ask] and [mre], then update your question.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to select from the subquery itself as that's where you're applying the aliasing. Try the following:

```
SELECT
CONCAT(a_understandable_name,b_understandable_name) as extended_name, 
DATETIME_TRUNC(start_time,DAY) as Day
FROM
(SELECT
a_random_name as a_understandable_name,
b_random_name as b_understandable_name,
start_time
FROM 'my_table')
```

Alternatively, you could use a CTE (common table expression) and write it as follows:

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT
a_random_name as a_understandable_name,
b_random_name as b_understandable_name,
start_time
FROM 'my_table')

SELECT
CONCAT(a_understandable_name,b_understandable_name) as extended_name, 
DATETIME_TRUNC(start_time,DAY) as Day
FROM CTE
```